# Which encoding is this?

Tags: php, decode, encode

I've got this in a variable when I unserialize an object:

GRANITVÃ„GEN 10 B

which is serialized with the function `serialize` in PHP

But the correct text should be GRANITVÄGEN 10 B

any ideas?

Comment: Where did the object come from? A good source gives the encoding used. What did you try to solve this yourself?

Comment: It came from a soap-request, and no, no encoding were used :(

Comment: But it's stored in my database with correct formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've got UTF-8 on one server and ANSI on another, although the place you got the data from should have told you the encoding, so your best bet is to go searching there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be UTF-8 displayed as ISO-8859-1 or similar.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely UTF-8, displayed in a wrong encoding.
Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence to see why you're seeing a few characters.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do a utf8_decode.. but I didn't think I had to do it cause it was already stored correct in my db?